# Very slow loading model in Django Admin and DRF API

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a model with 11 million instances (there are no problems when I test the model on a small amount of data). **The model does NOT have any ForeignKey or ManyToMany fields**. When I try to load a page with my model (DRF API or Django Admin) the page loads for about 5-7 minutes, also the whole system starts to slow down. When i'm working with other models there is no such problem.

---

**Model:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    process_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    dep_name_l1 = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    worksite = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_close = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    client_type = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    address_full = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True, blank=True)
    work = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True, blank=True)
    mark_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    mark_by_serv = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    mark_by_add = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=4000, null=True, blank=True)
    building_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, blank=True)
    mrf_name = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True, blank=True)
    filial = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    given_main_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    checked_main_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_difference_of_main_works = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    given_additional_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    checked_additional_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_difference_of_additional_works = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    calculated_all_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    checked_all_works_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_difference_of_all_works = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_matching_the_manual = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    logs = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

---

I filled this model with a script that took data from another DB, so there are no fields like `unique=True` or `db_index=True`.

---

**View:**

```
class MyModelView(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
    mixins.ListModelMixin, 
    mixins.CreateModelMixin, 
    GenericViewSet
):
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('pk')
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_class = MyModelFilter
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend, )
    pagination_class = ResultsSetPagination
```

---

**Serializer:**

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'  # I know this is not the best practice
```

---

**Filter:**

```
class MyModelFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    process_number = django_filters.Filter(name='process_number', lookup_expr='icontains')
    process_number_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='process_number', lookup_expr='exact')

    order_number = django_filters.Filter(name='order_number', lookup_expr='icontains')
    order_number_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='order_number', lookup_expr='exact')

    dep_name_l1 = django_filters.Filter(name='dep_name_l1', lookup_expr='icontains')
    dep_name_l1_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='dep_name_l1', lookup_expr='exact')

    worksite = django_filters.Filter(name='worksite', lookup_expr='icontains')
    worksite_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='worksite', lookup_expr='exact')

    date_create_gte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_create', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='gte')
    date_create_lte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_create', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='lte')

    date_end_gte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_end', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='gte')
    date_end_lte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_end', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='lte')

    date_close_gte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_close', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='gte')
    date_close_lte = django_filters.DateFilter(name='date_close', input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'], lookup_expr='lte')

    client_type = django_filters.Filter(name='client_type', lookup_expr='icontains')
    client_type_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='client_type', lookup_expr='exact')

    account = django_filters.Filter(name='account', lookup_expr='icontains')
    account_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='account', lookup_expr='exact')

    order_status = django_filters.Filter(name='order_status', lookup_expr='icontains')
    order_status_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='order_status', lookup_expr='exact')

    filial = django_filters.Filter(name='filial', lookup_expr='icontains')
    filial_number_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='filial', lookup_expr='exact')

    mrf_name = django_filters.Filter(name='mrf_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
    mrf_name_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='mrf_name', lookup_expr='exact')

    is_difference_of_main_works = django_filters.Filter(name='is_difference_of_main_works', lookup_expr='icontains')
    is_difference_of_main_works_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='is_difference_of_main_works', lookup_expr='exact')

    is_difference_of_additional_works = django_filters.Filter(
        name='is_difference_of_additional_works',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )
    is_difference_of_additional_works_exact = django_filters.Filter(
        name='is_difference_of_main_works',
        lookup_expr='exact'
    )

    is_difference_of_all_works = django_filters.Filter(
        name='is_difference_of_all_works',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )
    is_difference_of_all_works_exact = django_filters.Filter(
        name='is_difference_of_all_works',
        lookup_expr='exact'
    )

    status = django_filters.Filter(name='status', lookup_expr='icontains')
    status_exact = django_filters.Filter(name='status', lookup_expr='exact')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'process_number',
            'order_number',
            'dep_name_l1',
            'worksite',
            'date_create',
            'date_end',
            'date_close',
            'client_type',
            'account',
            'order_status',
            'filial',
            'mrf_name',
            'is_difference_of_main_works',
            'is_difference_of_additional_works',
            'is_difference_of_all_works',
        ]
```

---

**Paginator:**

```
class ResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        next_page_number, previous_page_number = (None, None)
        if self.page.has_next():
            next_page_number = self.page.next_page_number()
        if self.page.has_previous():
            previous_page_number = self.page.previous_page_number()
        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('current', self.page.number),
            ('next', next_page_number),
            ('previous', previous_page_number),
            ('page_size', self.page.paginator.per_page),
            ('results', data)
        ]))
```

---

**Admin:**

```
admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

---

I tried to remove the filters, change the pagination, display only the ids, but nothing helped. I suppose that the matter is in a large amount of data, although pagination should help in such cases. Google only found topics about optimizing models with relations. I will be happy for any help! Thanks!

- *Platform: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*
- *Python version: 3.5.2*
- *Django version: 1.11*
- *DRF version: 3.6.2*
- *DB: PostgreSQL*
- *Postgres version: psql major version 9.5, server major version 9.6.*

Comment: is it happening in your local development machine or in your production machine?

Comment: In my local machine

Comment: Have you tried a select query in your local db shell? It should be slower too if you don't have a very strong spec hardwares.

Comment: I have tried to select the query by ORM in Django shell. The request took a very long time too.

Comment: Not the ORM shell. I meant the actual database shell e.g. mysql, postgres, sqlite etc.

Comment: When I will be at work, I'll try, thanx!

Comment: The problem was on my local machine. The fact is that for some reason all the RAM and the CP were occupied. I could not understand why. Perhaps for such amounts of data, the local machine is not the best option. I tested this model on a production machine and everything is working fine.